# Django deployment on Heroku

Tags: django, performance, heroku, hosting

Recently I have deployed my Django web app to Heroku. while testing and running the app on local, the performance is OK. but as soon as I deployed on Heroku, and even up scaling to 2x dynos, it is still slow. like, login in and loading each page takes up-to 10 seconds. also, loading of static pages are fast on Heroku. while interacting with DB and s3 becket, it get so slow. DB and storage is on AWS.

Comment: maybe your dynos are not on the same region with DB/S3?

Comment: Fast enough on my side

Comment: @GaëtanGR did you register and login also?

Comment: @Ersain yes. the Heroku app is in US region of Heroku, and the DB is on Mumbai (south Asian) region of AWS. does that make much of deference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while and coming back to the office, I have implemented two DBs. one is for production and other one is for development. production database lives on RDS AWS. it works fine as normal. the testing DB is in my local machines. I fixed the issue by configuring AWS, RDS in Heroku.